# ADF: use the output from a lookup activity on another activity in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a lookup activity (Get_ID) that returns:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "TRGT_VAL": "10000"
        },
        {
            "TRGT_VAL": "52000"
        }
    ],
(...)
```

I want to use these 2 values from TRGT_VAL in a WHERE clause of a query in another activity. I'm using

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column in ',activity('Get_ID').output.value[0].TRGT_VAL)
```

But only the first value of 10000 is being taken into account. How to get the whole list?

Comment: It's kind of fiddly but you can use a For Each activity to run through the output from the Lookup, then have an array variable, an Append Variable activity inside the For Each loop, then join them at the end, like `@join(variables('arrWorking'), ';')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using a lot of replaces:

```
@concat('(',replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Get_ID').output.value),'{',''),' ',''),'"',''),'TRGT_VAL:',''),'[',''),'}',''),']',''),')')
```

```
Output
{
    "name": "AptitudeCF",
    "value": "(10000,52000)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using big expression with lot of replace functions, you can use String interpolation syntax and frame your query. Below is query which you can consider.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column in (@{activity('Get_ID').output.value[0].TRGT_VAL},@{activity('Get_ID').output.value[1].TRGT_VAL)
```